# That day that was 500 Days ago

Tags: riddle

> The day you are looking for is 500 Days ago,
>
> but, tomorrow, it is still 500 Days ago,
>
> and two days ago, it was still 500 Days ago.
>
> That Day was happy for some, but for some it wasn't.

When am I?

---

Note:  You do not need to involve the date and time this puzzle was posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be

> June 6, 1944, sometimes known as D-Day, D being the Roman numeral for 500?
>
>  I'm not sure you could say it was *happy* for some, though it certainly contributed to an Allied victory, which itself was very happy for many.
>
>  The Nazis definitely did a big frowny face because of D-Day, that's for sure.
>
>  The *event* will always have occurred on that specific date - calling it "500 Day[s ago]" is just a wordplay trick.
>
>  The only part that doesn't quite work is the word "ago", as substituting "D" in for "500" doesn't make the sentence make any grammatical sense.

Comment: That was the intended solution.

Comment: @wythagoras Thank you! I'm just very self-conscious about answers I'm not 100% sure of.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the answer is

> July 17, 2009

Explanation:

> July 17, 2009 was the release date of the movie [500 Days of Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/500_Days_of_Summer). The title of the movie remains "500 Days of Summer" regardless of what day it currently is; while the events of the movie were happy for the character Summer (the main female character/romantic interest), they weren't happy for the character Tom (the male protagonist).

Comment: Not the answer, but it is reasonable.

Comment: For my first answer on Puzzling.SE, I'm happy with "reasonable".